Procedural texture looks granular with EEVEE -- how to smooth?
Noob here -- I religiously followed this tutorial (Procedural Saturn Planet Material):
https://youtu.be/cxS_4tpKOa4?si=ZMdWHB3BLWq1opYU
But his render engine was Cycles, mine is EEVEE. Because of this, my result looks a little different: whereas his looks very realistic and smooth, and the ring transparency is visible, my texture looks too granular, not smooth enough, and you can't really see the ring transparency.
My Saturn:

Nodes for Saturn Rings shading:


Nodes for Saturn Planet shading:


I've tentatively played around with some of the nodes, without success. I blindly followed the tutorial step-by-step without knowing much about how it all works, so I don't want to f- anything up by tweaking things.
Is there a simple, straight-forwards way of smoothing the ring and planet textures and making the Saturn ring transparency visible?

the granularity comes from "aliasing" - it is because the scale of your noise texture is too big, and so there's discontinuity between pixels. Decrease the scale of noises.

To view transparent materials in Eevee, you need to go to Viewport Display and change the Blend Mode to Alpha Hashed.

Thanks for the responses. Both helped:)

Glad I could help!
If the answer solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as accepted, so the question doesn't keep getting bumped in the queue.  ;)

@SkyeBD Accepting answers is not something you do, right? ;)

@GordonBrinkmann  You and me both man

@aidan-j-rhoden omg I'm sorry I literally have just seen this now, I didn't realise 'accepting answers' was a thing, thanks for pointing it out to me!

@SkyeBD Hey no problem man, and thanks!
